# How to sort regex output into table?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my current pattern:

```
(?<=(\[|\())(.*?)(?=(]|\)))
```

Here is the string input:

```
[StringA1] (StringA2) (StringA3) (StringA4)
[StringB1] (StringB2) (StringB3) (StringB4) (StringB5)
[StringC1] (StringC2) (StringC3)
```

Here is the output:

```
StringA1
StringA2
StringA3
StringA4
StringB1
StringB2
StringB3
StringB4
StringB5
StringC1
StringC2
StringC3
```

I want to put the strings into a table, as follows:

```
     | Column1  | Column2  | Column3  | Column4  | Column5
Row1 | StringA1 | StringA2 | StringA3 | StringA4 |
Row2 | StringB1 | StringB2 | StringB3 | StringB4 | StringB5
Row3 | StringC1 | StringC2 | StringC3 |          |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you get your input-string per row? Then you could split the input-string by regex instead of matching it. Like this:

```
var input = @"[StringA1] (StringA2) (StringA3) (StringA4)";
// strip leading and trailing brackets...
var stripped = input.Substring(1, input.Length - 2);
// ...and split by "closing-bracket|whitespace|opening-bracket"
var split = Regex.Split(stripped, @"[\)\]]\s[\(\[]");
```

*And next time, please show at least some effort what you've tried...*

**EDIT**
The `Regex.Split` only removes the matching-parts - in your case the closing-bracket|space|opening-bracket, this wont touch the leading and trailing brackets.

You can do it your way, but that regular expression would be much more complex. The one you've created only matches the first column, so you have to repeat that n-times for all possible columns and make the repeated groups optional since you've posted rows with different column count. Because of that I think the `Regex.Split` way is much easier than your approach.

As an alternative you could combine `String.Split` with LinQ to get rid of the regex-usage:

```
String.Split(' ', input).Select(x => x.Substring(1, x.Length - 2)).ToArray()
```

which might be more performant if you have to process many rows...

Comment: Okay, so the solution is to use `Regex.Split` and remove everything not needed, instead of directly searching for the desired strings.

I did try, by the way. The regex pattern I wrote successfully matches the desired strings, but afterwards, I had no method to put them into a table while retaining formatting.

This may sound silly, but is there a regex solution to removing the first and last brackets of the line, or is this just the nature of using `Regex.Split`

Comment: @HuiZui Updated my answer. Yes, thats the nature of `Regex.Split`, it only removes the matched-split-string...

Comment: I see. Thank you again.